# 1064; You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have this error:

> 1064; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'n')' at line 1
>   INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick'n');

My query:

```
INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick'n')
```

i don't know what to do

Comment: You obviously have an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability: `'Stick'n'` is NOT a valid mysql string.

Comment: @MarcB how is this an injection issue? It's merely an unescaped quote.

Comment: @Martin: the fact that the quote is unquoted means OP is unaware of how to write a proper query, which means it's injection vulnerable. even if that data doesn't come from "outside" - it's still a problem. you can trivially inject yourself using nothing but "internal" data.

Comment: The symptoms are the same but it's an escaping issue rather than a malicious attack issue, of course it *could* be a route for a later attack but we have no idea where this data comes from or what DB interfaces are being used. Yes OP is not up to speed and yes it could potentially be a route for DB compromise but I don't think that's an actual issue here (sorry I'm sounding more and more penickerty as I write this) :-/

Comment: Anyhow, to the OP it is well worth (aka *crucial*) you read up on Marc B's link and get to know injection attacks and how to prevent them :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick\'n');
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the quote:

```
INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick\'n');
```

For more info refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use double `'` to indicate `apostrophe` inside string literal:

```
CREATE TABLE  oc_ul_alias(`query` VARCHAR(100), keyword VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO oc_ul_alias(`query`, keyword) 
VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick''n');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ae8/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try with `INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick''n');`

you need to escape some char, check mysql manual

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error notices typically mean that the error actually occured at the character before the near reference, so you're looking at the characters **before** `n')`

Your error notice gives you the issue in the SQL:

> INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834',
>   'Stick'n');

so the error is caused by the extra single quote in your `Stick'n` so you need to escape the character with `\` preceeding it.

```
 INSERT INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword) VALUES ('product_id=26834', 'Stick\'n');
```